# Running counter each time a function is executed (VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, function

I am struggling slightly with my indexing of my array. I want the upper bound of the array to be the amount of time's the Function RandomizeDice executes. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Function RandomizeDice()
    RandomizeDice = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
End Function

Sub RollDice()
    Dim DiceOne() As Variant
    Dim DiceTwo() As Variant
    Dim SumDice() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    ReDim DiceOne(i) As Variant
    ReDim DiceTwo(i) As Variant
    ReDim SumDice(i) As Variant
    Call arraySet(DiceOne(), DiceTwo(), SumDice())
    Debug.Print SumDice(i)
    'Debug.Print SumDice(0)
   ' Debug.Print ("Dice: " & DiceOne(0) & " " & DiceTwo(0))
   ' Debug.Print ("Sum: " & DiceOne(0) + DiceTwo(0))
End Sub
Sub arraySet(ByRef a() As Variant, b() As Variant, c() As Variant)
    'Dim DiceOne() As Integer
    'Dim DiceTwo() As Integer
    Dim i, j As Integer
    'Dim intSumDice() As Integer
    For i = 0 To j = i + 1
        a(i) = RandomizeDice() 'dice1
        b(i) = RandomizeDice() 'dice2
        c(i) = a(i) + b(i) 'sum
    Next i
    Debug.Print i
    Debug.Print ("Dice: " & a(0) & " " & b(0))
    Debug.Print ("Sum: " & a(0) + b(0))
End Sub
```

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn you really helped me with my last post on this topic so you maybe gave some insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using a static variable.  The value of a static variable persists between function calls.  Please see below for a solution.  Run the `Sub Main` in the code below several times to see it work.

```
Option Explicit

Public Type structPairOfDice
    diceOne As Integer
    diceTwo As Integer
    rollNum As Integer
End Type

Function RandomizeDice() As Integer
    RandomizeDice = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
End Function

Function RollDice(structDice As structPairOfDice) As structPairOfDice

    Static iRollNum As Integer

    iRollNum = iRollNum + 1
    With structDice
        .rollNum = iRollNum
        .diceOne = RandomizeDice()
        .diceTwo = RandomizeDice()
    End With

    RollDice = structDice

End Function

Sub PrintResults(structDice As structPairOfDice)

    With structDice
        Debug.Print "Roll #: " & .rollNum
        Debug.Print "Dice:   " & .diceOne & ", " & .diceTwo
        Debug.Print "Sum:    " & .diceOne + .diceTwo
        Debug.Print
    End With

End Sub

Sub Main()

    Dim structDice As structPairOfDice

    PrintResults RollDice(structDice)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `RollDice` such as it takes the number of rolls as parameter

```
Sub RollDice(ByVal nRolls As Long)
    ReDim DiceOne(1 To nRolls) As Long, DiceTwo(1 To nRolls) As Long, SumDice(1 To nRolls) As Long
    For nRolls = 1 To nRolls
        DiceOne(nRolls) = RandomizeDice()
        DiceTwo(nRolls) = RandomizeDice()
        SumDice(nRolls) = DiceOne(nRolls) + DiceTwo(nRolls)
    Next
    ' Now do what you want with these arrays
End Sub

Sub testing()
    RollDice 100
End Sub
```